# Mount or sync an S3 versioned bucket with rewind - back in time

Tags: filesystems, rsync, amazon-s3, rclone, ceph

Assuming I have an S3 versioned bucket (backed by Ceph), I would like to restore from it at a specific time. [`mcli` has a `--rewind` feature](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-cp.html) that allows some operations to time-travel into the past taking advantage of the versions. Unfortunately, [this does not work with Ceph](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/issues/1760). Is there some other easy to use solution to restore object versions at specific time? I'm aware there are many S3 tools out there, but I haven't found such rewinding feature anywhere else. Ideally, it would be either a r/o mount like `s3fs`/`rclone mount` at a given time so rsync can be used on it, or a sync operation, like `rclone sync` with a rewind option. I'm willing to do a bit of scripting if absolutely necessary.